# WCF client web service - what do the TypeId's stand for?

Tags: csom, web-services, wcf

CSOM speaks to SharePoint in WCF web service calls.

Here is an example of a SharePoint WCF web service XML request from SharePoint 2010:

```
<Request AddExpandoFieldTypeSuffix="true" SchemaVersion="14.0.0.0" LibraryVersion="16.0.0.0"
         ApplicationName=".NET Library" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/clientquery/2009">
    <Actions>
        <ObjectPath Id="2" ObjectPathId="1"/>
        <ObjectPath Id="4" ObjectPathId="3"/>
        <ObjectPath Id="6" ObjectPathId="5"/>
        <ObjectPath Id="8" ObjectPathId="7"/>
        <ObjectPath Id="10" ObjectPathId="9"/>
        <Query Id="11" ObjectPathId="9">
            <Query SelectAllProperties="true">
                <Properties/>
            </Query>
            <ChildItemQuery SelectAllProperties="true">
                <Properties/>
            </ChildItemQuery>
        </Query>
    </Actions>
    <ObjectPaths>
        <StaticProperty Id="1" TypeId="{3747adcd-a3c3-41b9-bfab-4a64dd2f1e0a}" Name="Current"/>
        <Property Id="3" ParentId="1" Name="Site"/>
        <Property Id="5" ParentId="3" Name="RootWeb"/>
        <Property Id="7" ParentId="5" Name="SiteUserInfoList"/>
        <Method Id="9" ParentId="7" Name="GetItems">
            <Parameters>
                <Parameter TypeId="{3d248d7b-fc86-40a3-aa97-02a75d69fb8a}">
                    <Property Name="AllowIncrementalResults" Type="Boolean">false</Property>
                    <Property Name="DatesInUtc" Type="Boolean">true</Property>
                    <Property Name="FolderServerRelativePath" Type="Null"/>
                    <Property Name="FolderServerRelativeUrl" Type="Null"/>
                    <Property Name="ListItemCollectionPosition" Type="Null"/>
                    <Property Name="ViewXml" Type="String">&lt;View Scope="RecursiveAll"&gt;&lt;RowLimit&gt;5&lt;/RowLimit&gt;&lt;/View&gt;</Property>
                </Parameter>
            </Parameters>
        </Method>
    </ObjectPaths>
</Request>
```

Within this request there are `TypeId` elements like this:

`TypeId="{3747adcd-a3c3-41b9-bfab-4a64dd2f1e0a}"`

These type ID represent Class names in the WCF class library. Is there a way to look these up by `TypeId`? Do they tend to change in between schema versions?

Answer (score 0):

Linda Zhang technet forum moderator gave me this answer here

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Sharepoint/en-US/55ab013c-de96-4f37-99c3-be7ee4a7d7a3/what-do-typeids-in-wcf-web-service-requests-stand-for-are-they-constants?forum=sharepointgeneral&prof=required

A TypeId is a GUID that identifies the Client-Side Object Model (CSOM) Object type.

The Name is the name of the static method/property to call or is used to access on the CSOM Object type that is specified by the TypeId attribute. It must be the name of a valid static method/property of the CSOM Object type.

The TypeId “3747adcd-a3c3-41b9-bfab-4a64dd2f1e0a” is the reference to “Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RequestContext”. Use “Current” property to return the SPContext for the current HttpContext.

The TypeId “3d248d7b-fc86-40a3-aa97-02a75d69fb8a” is referencing “Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery”.

SharePoint CSOM Protocol:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd958478(v=office.12).aspx

Types, methods, and properties of the SharePoint CSOM API Protocol:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd946239(v=office.12).aspx

A PDF of SharePoint CSOM API Protocol information:

http://interoperability.blob.core.windows.net/files/MS-CSOM/[MS-CSOM]-160226.pdf